# Get Data out of JSON list

Tags: javascript, arraylist

I have a JSON list weatherforecast from openweathermap, my problem is : How to get Just the weather data for 18:00:00 for all 5 days. How can i get the data out of the list?

```
$.support.cors = true;
$.ajax({
    url: "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=hamburg&units=metric&APPID=apikey",
    cache: false,
    success: function (dataForecast) {

        $("#tempMo").append(dataForecast.list[0].main.temp_max + "c");

        $.inArray("18:00:00", dataForecast.list)
```

Comment: `I have a JSON list` what is a JSON list? and what does it actually look like (since you need an API key to get it, perhaps you could share the data only you can see

Comment: Post a sample of the JSON data the API returns, instead of your AJAX call.

Comment: posted the data below.

Answer (score 0):

```
{
"cod": "200",
"message": 0.0047,
"cnt": 40,
"list": [
    {
        "dt": 1553785200,
        "main": {
            "temp": 11.98,
            "temp_min": 11.98,
            "temp_max": 12.14,
            "pressure": 1033.34,
            "sea_level": 1033.34,
            "grnd_level": 1028.71,
            "humidity": 78,
            "temp_kf": -0.16
        },
        "weather": [
            {
                "id": 500,
                "main": "Rain",
                "description": "light rain",
                "icon": "10d"
            }
        ],
        "clouds": {
            "all": 68
        },
        "wind": {
            "speed": 3.93,
            "deg": 320.508
        },
        "rain": {
            "3h": 0.015
        },
        "sys": {
            "pod": "d"
        },
        "dt_txt": "2019-03-28 15:00:00"
    },
    {
        "dt": 1553796000,
        "main": {
            "temp": 10.91,
            "temp_min": 10.91,
            "temp_max": 11.03,
            "pressure": 1033.72,
            "sea_level": 1033.72,
            "grnd_level": 1029.13,
            "humidity": 77,
            "temp_kf": -0.12
        },
        "weather": [
            {
                "id": 500,
                "main": "Rain",
                "description": "light rain",
                "icon": "10n"
            }
        ],
        "clouds": {
            "all": 76
        },
        "wind": {
            "speed": 2.91,
            "deg": 319.003
        },
        "rain": {
            "3h": 0.005
        },
        "sys": {
            "pod": "n"
        },
        "dt_txt": "2019-03-28 18:00:00"
    },
    {
        "dt": 1553806800,
        "main": {
            "temp": 8.69,
            "temp_min": 8.69,
            "temp_max": 8.77,
            "pressure": 1034.46,
            "sea_level": 1034.46,
            "grnd_level": 1029.98,
            "humidity": 86,
            "temp_kf": -0.08
        },
        "weather": [
            {
                "id": 500,
                "main": "Rain",
                "description": "light rain",
                "icon": "10n"
            }
        ],
        "clouds": {
            "all": 24
        },
        "wind": {
            "speed": 2.63,
            "deg": 312.002
        },
        "rain": {
            "3h": 0.01
        },
        "sys": {
            "pod": "n"
        },
        "dt_txt": "2019-03-28 21:00:00"
    },
    {
        "dt": 1553817600,
        "main": {
            "temp": 5.12,
            "temp_min": 5.12,
            "temp_max": 5.16,
            "pressure": 1034.12,
            "sea_level": 1034.12,
            "grnd_level": 1029.66,
            "humidity": 95,
            "temp_kf": -0.04
        },
        "weather": [
            {
                "id": 500,
                "main": "Rain",
                "description": "light rain",
                "icon": "10n"
            }
        ],
        "clouds": {
            "all": 0
        },
        "wind": {
            "speed": 1.3,
            "deg": 232.007
        },
        "rain": {
            "3h": 0.005
        },
        "sys": {
            "pod": "n"
        },
        "dt_txt": "2019-03-29 00:00:00"
    },
    {
        "dt": 1553828400,
        "main": {
            "temp": 3.34,
            "temp_min": 3.34,
            "temp_max": 3.34,
            "pressure": 1033.3,
            "sea_level": 1033.3,
            "grnd_level": 1028.64,
            "humidity": 91,
            "temp_kf": 0
        },
        "weather": [
            {
                "id": 800,
                "main": "Clear",
                "description": "clear sky",
                "icon": "01n"
            }
        ],
        "clouds": {
            "all": 0
        },
        "wind": {
            "speed": 1.31,
            "deg": 198.501
        },
        "rain": {},
        "sys": {
            "pod": "n"
        },
        "dt_txt": "2019-03-29 03:00:00"
    },
    {
        "dt": 1553839200,
        "main": {
            "temp": 3.85,
            "temp_min": 3.85,
            "temp_max": 3.85,
            "pressure": 1032.89,
            "sea_level": 1032.89,
            "grnd_level": 1028.24,
            "humidity": 86,
            "temp_kf": 0
        },
        "weather": [
            {
                "id": 800,
                "main": "Clear",
                "description": "clear sky",
                "icon": "01d"
            }
        ],
        "clouds": {
            "all": 0
        },
        "wind": {
            "speed": 2.22,
            "deg": 205.009
        },
        "rain": {},
        "sys": {
            "pod": "d"
        },
        "dt_txt": "2019-03-29 06:00:00"
    },
    {
        "dt": 1553850000,
        "main": {
            "temp": 11.34,
            "temp_min": 11.34,
            "temp_max": 11.34,
            "pressure": 1032.31,
            "sea_level": 1032.31,
            "grnd_level": 1027.8,
            "humidity": 89,
            "temp_kf": 0
        },
        "weather": [
            {
                "id": 500,
                "main": "Rain",
                "description": "light rain",
                "icon": "10d"
            }
        ],
        "clouds": {
            "all": 0
        },
        "wind": {
            "speed": 3.65,
            "deg": 231.005
        },
        "rain": {
            "3h": 0.005
        },
        "sys": {
            "pod": "d"
        },
        "dt_txt": "2019-03-29 09:00:00"
    },
    {
        "dt": 1553860800,
        "main": {
            "temp": 14.27,
            "temp_min": 14.27,
            "temp_max": 14.27,
            "pressure": 1030.73,
            "sea_level": 1030.73,
            "grnd_level": 1026.24,
            "humidity": 81,
            "temp_kf": 0
        },
        "weather": [
            {
                "id": 800,
                "main": "Clear",
                "description": "clear sky",
                "icon": "02d"
            }
        ],
        "clouds": {
            "all": 8
        },
        "wind": {
            "speed": 5.26,
            "deg": 244.002
        },
        "rain": {},
        "sys": {
            "pod": "d"
        },
        "dt_txt": "2019-03-29 12:00:00"
    },
    {
        "dt": 1553871600,
        "main": {
            "temp": 14.73,
            "temp_min": 14.73,
            "temp_max": 14.73,
            "pressure": 1028.76,
            "sea_level": 1028.76,
            "grnd_level": 1024.33,
            "humidity": 72,
            "temp_kf": 0
        },
        "weather": [
            {
                "id": 800,
                "main": "Clear",
                "description": "clear sky",
                "icon": "01d"
            }
        ],
        "clouds": {
            "all": 0
        },
        "wind": {
            "speed": 5.01,
            "deg": 253.507
        },
        "rain": {},
        "sys": {
            "pod": "d"
        },
        "dt_txt": "2019-03-29 15:00:00"
    },
    {
        "dt": 1553882400,
        "main": {
            "temp": 12.09,
            "temp_min": 12.09,
            "temp_max": 12.09,
            "pressure": 1027.67,
            "sea_level": 1027.67,
            "grnd_level": 1023.22,
            "humidity": 68,
            "temp_kf": 0
        },
        "weather": [
            {
                "id": 800,
                "main": "Clear",
                "description": "clear sky",
                "icon": "01n"
            }
        ],
        "clouds": {
            "all": 0
        },
        "wind": {
            "speed": 3.22,
            "deg": 252.503
        },
        "rain": {},
        "sys": {
            "pod": "n"
        },
        "dt_txt": "2019-03-29 18:00:00"
    },
    {
        "dt": 1553893200,
        "main": {
            "temp": 7.99,
            "temp_min": 7.99,
            "temp_max": 7.99,
            "pressure": 1027.11,
            "sea_level": 1027.11,
            "grnd_level": 1022.56,
            "humidity": 88,
            "temp_kf": 0
        },
        "weather": [
            {
                "id": 800,
                "main": "Clear",
                "description": "clear sky",
                "icon": "01n"
            }
        ],
        "clouds": {
            "all": 0
        },
        "wind": {
            "speed": 2.52,
            "deg": 238.502
        },
        "rain": {},
        "sys": {
            "pod": "n"
        },
        "dt_txt": "2019-03-29 21:00:00"
    },
    {
        "dt": 1553904000,
        "main": {
            "temp": 5.35,
            "temp_min": 5.35,
            "temp_max": 5.35,
            "pressure": 1026.24,
            "sea_level": 1026.24,
            "grnd_level": 1021.73,
            "humidity": 88,
            "temp_kf": 0
        },
        "weather": [
            {
                "id": 800,
                "main": "Clear",
                "description": "clear sky",
                "icon": "01n"
            }
        ],
        "clouds": {
            "all": 0
        },
        "wind": {
            "speed": 1.25,
            "deg": 241.5
        },
        "rain": {},
        "sys": {
            "pod": "n"
        },
        "dt_txt": "2019-03-30 00:00:00"
    },
    {
        "dt": 1553914800,
        "main": {
            "temp": 4.34,
            "temp_min": 4.34,
            "temp_max": 4.34,
            "pressure": 1024.74,
            "sea_level": 1024.74,
            "grnd_level": 1020.17,
            "humidity": 84,
            "temp_kf": 0
        },
        "weather": [
            {
                "id": 800,
                "main": "Clear",
                "description": "clear sky",
                "icon": "01n"
            }
        ],
        "clouds": {
            "all": 0
        },
        "wind": {
            "speed": 1.58,
            "deg": 200.506
        },
        "rain": {},
        "sys": {
            "pod": "n"
        },
        "dt_txt": "2019-03-30 03:00:00"
    },
    {
        "dt": 1553925600,
        "main": {
            "temp": 5.69,
            "temp_min": 5.69,
            "temp_max": 5.69,
            "pressure": 1023.53,
            "sea_level": 1023.53,
            "grnd_level": 1018.95,
            "humidity": 85,
            "temp_kf": 0
        },
        "weather": [
            {
                "id": 800,
                "main": "Clear",
                "description": "clear sky",
                "icon": "01d"
            }
        ],
        "clouds": {
            "all": 0
        },
        "wind": {
            "speed": 3.8,
            "deg": 214.01
        },
        "rain": {},
        "sys": {
            "pod": "d"
        },
        "dt_txt": "2019-03-30 06:00:00"
    },
    {
        "dt": 1553936400,
        "main": {
            "temp": 12.49,
            "temp_min": 12.49,
            "temp_max": 12.49,
            "pressure": 1022.76,
            "sea_level": 1022.76,
            "grnd_level": 1018.24,
            "humidity": 82,
            "temp_kf": 0
        },
        "weather": [
            {
                "id": 800,
                "main": "Clear",
                "description": "clear sky",
                "icon": "01d"
            }
        ],
        "clouds": {
            "all": 0
        },
        "wind": {
            "speed": 4.5,
            "deg": 231
        },
        "rain": {},
        "sys": {
            "pod": "d"
        },
        "dt_txt": "2019-03-30 09:00:00"
    },
    {
        "dt": 1553947200,
        "main": {
            "temp": 15.47,
            "temp_min": 15.47,
            "temp_max": 15.47,
            "pressure": 1021.13,
            "sea_level": 1021.13,
            "grnd_level": 1016.69,
            "humidity": 77,
            "temp_kf": 0
        },
        "weather": [
            {
                "id": 800,
                "main": "Clear",
                "description": "clear sky",
                "icon": "01d"
            }
        ],
        "clouds": {
            "all": 0
        },
        "wind": {
            "speed": 5.56,
            "deg": 253.006
        },
        "rain": {},
        "sys": {
            "pod": "d"
        },
        "dt_txt": "2019-03-30 12:00:00"
    },
    {
        "dt": 1553958000,
        "main": {
            "temp": 15.05,
            "temp_min": 15.05,
            "temp_max": 15.05,
            "pressure": 1019.84,
            "sea_level": 1019.84,
            "grnd_level": 1015.41,
            "humidity": 68,
            "temp_kf": 0
        },
        "weather": [
            {
                "id": 803,
                "main": "Clouds",
                "description": "broken clouds",
                "icon": "04d"
            }
        ],
        "clouds": {
            "all": 76
        },
        "wind": {
            "speed": 6.26,
            "deg": 276.501
        },
        "rain": {},
        "sys": {
            "pod": "d"
        },
        "dt_txt": "2019-03-30 15:00:00"
    },
    {
        "dt": 1553968800,
        "main": {
            "temp": 11.18,
            "temp_min": 11.18,
            "temp_max": 11.18,
            "pressure": 1020.08,
            "sea_level": 1020.08,
            "grnd_level": 1015.72,
            "humidity": 63,
            "temp_kf": 0
        },
        "weather": [
            {
                "id": 800,
                "main": "Clear",
                "description": "clear sky",
                "icon": "01n"
            }
        ],
        "clouds": {
            "all": 0
        },
        "wind": {
            "speed": 5.35,
            "deg": 294.003
        },
        "rain": {},
        "sys": {
            "pod": "n"
        },
        "dt_txt": "2019-03-30 18:00:00"
    },
    {
        "dt": 1553979600,
        "main": {
            "temp": 7.1,
            "temp_min": 7.1,
            "temp_max": 7.1,
            "pressure": 1021.4,
            "sea_level": 1021.4,
            "grnd_level": 1016.89,
            "humidity": 79,
            "temp_kf": 0
        },
        "weather": [
            {
                "id": 801,
                "main": "Clouds",
                "description": "few clouds",
                "icon": "02n"
            }
        ],
        "clouds": {
            "all": 12
        },
        "wind": {
            "speed": 4.09,
            "deg": 308
        },
        "rain": {},
        "sys": {
            "pod": "n"
        },
        "dt_txt": "2019-03-30 21:00:00"
    },
    {
        "dt": 1553990400,
        "main": {
            "temp": 5.48,
            "temp_min": 5.48,
            "temp_max": 5.48,
            "pressure": 1022.18,
            "sea_level": 1022.18,
            "grnd_level": 1017.64,
            "humidity": 95,
            "temp_kf": 0
        },
        "weather": [
            {
                "id": 802,
                "main": "Clouds",
                "description": "scattered clouds",
                "icon": "03n"
            }
        ],
        "clouds": {
            "all": 36
        },
        "wind": {
            "speed": 3.51,
            "deg": 315.004
        },
        "rain": {},
        "sys": {
            "pod": "n"
        },
        "dt_txt": "2019-03-31 00:00:00"
    },
    {
        "dt": 1554001200,
        "main": {
            "temp": 4.57,
            "temp_min": 4.57,
            "temp_max": 4.57,
            "pressure": 1023.18,
            "sea_level": 1023.18,
            "grnd_level": 1018.66,
            "humidity": 92,
            "temp_kf": 0
        },
        "weather": [
            {
                "id": 803,
                "main": "Clouds",
                "description": "broken clouds",
                "icon": "04n"
            }
        ],
        "clouds": {
            "all": 56
        },
        "wind": {
            "speed": 3.47,
            "deg": 321.501
        },
        "rain": {},
        "sys": {
            "pod": "n"
        },
        "dt_txt": "2019-03-31 03:00:00"
    },
    {
        "dt": 1554012000,
        "main": {
            "temp": 4.62,
            "temp_min": 4.62,
            "temp_max": 4.62,
            "pressure": 1024.67,
            "sea_level": 1024.67,
            "grnd_level": 1020.08,
            "humidity": 84,
            "temp_kf": 0
        },
        "weather": [
            {
                "id": 801,
                "main": "Clouds",
                "description": "few clouds",
                "icon": "02d"
            }
        ],
        "clouds": {
            "all": 24
        },
        "wind": {
            "speed": 3.53,
            "deg": 337.001
        },
        "rain": {},
        "sys": {
            "pod": "d"
        },
        "dt_txt": "2019-03-31 06:00:00"
    },
    {
        "dt": 1554022800,
        "main": {
            "temp": 7.4,
            "temp_min": 7.4,
            "temp_max": 7.4,
            "pressure": 1026.58,
            "sea_level": 1026.58,
            "grnd_level": 1022.03,
            "humidity": 79,
            "temp_kf": 0
        },
        "weather": [
            {
                "id": 800,
                "main": "Clear",
                "description": "clear sky",
                "icon": "01d"
            }
        ],
        "clouds": {
            "all": 0
        },
        "wind": {
            "speed": 4.56,
            "deg": 358.009
        },
        "rain": {},
        "sys": {
            "pod": "d"
        },
        "dt_txt": "2019-03-31 09:00:00"
    },
    {
        "dt": 1554033600,
        "main": {
            "temp": 8.55,
            "temp_min": 8.55,
            "temp_max": 8.55,
            "pressure": 1027.53,
            "sea_level": 1027.53,
            "grnd_level": 1022.98,
            "humidity": 76,
            "temp_kf": 0
        },
        "weather": [
            {
                "id": 800,
                "main": "Clear",
                "description": "clear sky",
                "icon": "02d"
            }
        ],
        "clouds": {
            "all": 8
        },
        "wind": {
            "speed": 4.68,
            "deg": 355.001
        },
        "rain": {},
        "sys": {
            "pod": "d"
        },
        "dt_txt": "2019-03-31 12:00:00"
    },
    {
        "dt": 1554044400,
        "main": {
            "temp": 7.77,
            "temp_min": 7.77,
            "temp_max": 7.77,
            "pressure": 1027.92,
            "sea_level": 1027.92,
            "grnd_level": 1023.41,
            "humidity": 67,
            "temp_kf": 0
        },
        "weather": [
            {
                "id": 803,
                "main": "Clouds",
                "description": "broken clouds",
                "icon": "04d"
            }
        ],
        "clouds": {
            "all": 64
        },
        "wind": {
            "speed": 4.21,
            "deg": 1.00049
        },
        "rain": {},
        "sys": {
            "pod": "d"
        },
        "dt_txt": "2019-03-31 15:00:00"
    },
    {
        "dt": 1554055200,
        "main": {
            "temp": 5.94,
            "temp_min": 5.94,
            "temp_max": 5.94,
            "pressure": 1028.8,
            "sea_level": 1028.8,
            "grnd_level": 1024.2,
            "humidity": 60,
            "temp_kf": 0
        },
        "weather": [
            {
                "id": 803,
                "main": "Clouds",
                "description": "broken clouds",
                "icon": "04n"
            }
        ],
        "clouds": {
            "all": 56
        },
        "wind": {
            "speed": 2.56,
            "deg": 6.00009
        },
        "rain": {},
        "sys": {
            "pod": "n"
        },
        "dt_txt": "2019-03-31 18:00:00"
    },
    {
        "dt": 1554066000,
        "main": {
            "temp": 3.91,
            "temp_min": 3.91,
            "temp_max": 3.91,
            "pressure": 1030.12,
            "sea_level": 1030.12,
            "grnd_level": 1025.42,
            "humidity": 63,
            "temp_kf": 0
        },
        "weather": [
            {
                "id": 803,
                "main": "Clouds",
                "description": "broken clouds",
                "icon": "04n"
            }
        ],
        "clouds": {
            "all": 56
        },
        "wind": {
            "speed": 1.36,
            "deg": 29.0056
        },
        "rain": {},
        "sys": {
            "pod": "n"
        },
        "dt_txt": "2019-03-31 21:00:00"
    },
    {
        "dt": 1554076800,
        "main": {
            "temp": 3.13,
            "temp_min": 3.13,
            "temp_max": 3.13,
            "pressure": 1030.55,
            "sea_level": 1030.55,
            "grnd_level": 1025.91,
            "humidity": 64,
            "temp_kf": 0
        },
        "weather": [
            {
                "id": 803,
                "main": "Clouds",
                "description": "broken clouds",
                "icon": "04n"
            }
        ],
        "clouds": {
            "all": 80
        },
        "wind": {
            "speed": 0.97,
            "deg": 355.003
        },
        "rain": {},
        "sys": {
            "pod": "n"
        },
        "dt_txt": "2019-04-01 00:00:00"
    },
    {
        "dt": 1554087600,
        "main": {
            "temp": 2.94,
            "temp_min": 2.94,
            "temp_max": 2.94,
            "pressure": 1030.73,
            "sea_level": 1030.73,
            "grnd_level": 1026.06,
            "humidity": 67,
            "temp_kf": 0
        },
        "weather": [
            {
                "id": 803,
                "main": "Clouds",
                "description": "broken clouds",
                "icon": "04n"
            }
        ],
        "clouds": {
            "all": 68
        },
        "wind": {
            "speed": 1.36,
            "deg": 2.50177
        },
        "rain": {},
        "sys": {
            "pod": "n"
        },
        "dt_txt": "2019-04-01 03:00:00"
    },
    {
        "dt": 1554098400,
        "main": {
            "temp": 2.29,
            "temp_min": 2.29,
            "temp_max": 2.29,
            "pressure": 1030.85,
            "sea_level": 1030.85,
            "grnd_level": 1026.21,
            "humidity": 71,
            "temp_kf": 0
        },
        "weather": [
            {
                "id": 800,
                "main": "Clear",
                "description": "clear sky",
                "icon": "02d"
            }
        ],
        "clouds": {
            "all": 8
        },
        "wind": {
            "speed": 1.32,
            "deg": 36
        },
        "rain": {},
        "sys": {
            "pod": "d"
        },
        "dt_txt": "2019-04-01 06:00:00"
    },
    {
        "dt": 1554109200,
        "main": {
            "temp": 6.72,
            "temp_min": 6.72,
            "temp_max": 6.72,
            "pressure": 1031.22,
            "sea_level": 1031.22,
            "grnd_level": 1026.71,
            "humidity": 83,
            "temp_kf": 0
        },
        "weather": [
            {
                "id": 800,
                "main": "Clear",
                "description": "clear sky",
                "icon": "01d"
            }
        ],
        "clouds": {
            "all": 0
        },
        "wind": {
            "speed": 2.11,
            "deg": 83.0005
        },
        "rain": {},
        "sys": {
            "pod": "d"
        },
        "dt_txt": "2019-04-01 09:00:00"
    },
    {
        "dt": 1554120000,
        "main": {
            "temp": 8,
            "temp_min": 8,
            "temp_max": 8,
            "pressure": 1029.87,
            "sea_level": 1029.87,
            "grnd_level": 1025.33,
            "humidity": 84,
            "temp_kf": 0
        },
        "weather": [
            {
                "id": 801,
                "main": "Clouds",
                "description": "few clouds",
                "icon": "02d"
            }
        ],
        "clouds": {
            "all": 12
        },
        "wind": {
            "speed": 2.28,
            "deg": 109
        },
        "rain": {},
        "sys": {
            "pod": "d"
        },
        "dt_txt": "2019-04-01 12:00:00"
    }
```